# dropdownlist into an ASP.Net GridView not binding correctly

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` with a `DropDownList`.
The `DropDownList` items need to be set into the code behind.
I checked online code samples and it looks I am supposed to code it this way:

```
<asp:GridView ID="DG_Table" runat="server" style="z-index: 1;autogeneratecolumns="False" 
onrowcommand="DG_Table_RowCommand"  
onrowdatabound="onrowdatabound">  

   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" >
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="field1" >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="field1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FieldValue") %>'></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Into code behind:

```
public void onrowdatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //check if is in edit mode
                if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
                {

                    DropDownList dropdownlist = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Name");
                    dropdownlist.DataSource = new List<string>() { "Pete", "Jack", "Steve", "Mike", "Rob", "Jim", "Eric" };
                    dropdownlist.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

When debugging, I can see that the debugger enters onrowdatabound.
At this time, 
`e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header`

This is probably normal at this stage. So the debugger exits the method.
I would expect the debugger to enter `onrowdatabound` again when attempting to add lines to the `DataGrid`.
Somehow it does not, so the `Datasource` is never set and the code later on tries to add a value to the `dropdownlist` which does not belong to the `dropdownlist.Items`, causing an execution error:

Additional information: `'Name' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items`.

(which is logical since the `dropdownlist.datasource` has never been set.

When `DG_Table.DataBind()` is called, there are 3 rows:

```
protected void B_Fill_Fennec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<fennec> list_fennec = new List<fennec>() { new fennec("Pete", "dev"), new fennec("Jack", "butcher"), new fennec("Steve", "wood chopper"), };

            GridView1.DataSource = list_fennec.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, FieldValue = x.Occupation });
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is this a typo? or this is how it is coded? style="z-index: 1;autogeneratecolumns="False"

Comment: If the onrowdatabound is not fired for each row, then probably there is something wrong with the data source that you are supplying. Can you try convert the LINQ query results into a list and use that as a data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your markup you have this line which is invalid:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Firstly because you open a `DropDownList` tag and close a `TextBox` tag. (I'm assuming this is an error when asking the question and altering your code).

Secondly `Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'` is not valid there (looks like this is half of a `TextBox` delcaration?

I think what you're trying to do is set the `SelectedValue` of the `Dropdown` to be the `Name` of from the `Datasource` something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="DG_Table" runat="server" style="z-index: 1;autogeneratecolumns="False" 
onrowcommand="DG_Table_RowCommand"  
onrowdatabound="onrowdatabound">  

   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" >
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:HiddenField id="hdn_Name" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
         <asp:DropDownList ID="Name" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="field1" >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="field1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FieldValue") %>'></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public void onrowdatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //check if is in edit mode
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
               DropDownList dropdownlist = DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Name");
               dropdownlist.DataSource = new List<string>() { "Pete", "Jack", "Steve", "Mike", "Rob", "Jim", "Eric" };
               dropdownlist.DataBind();
               var nameField = e.Row.FindControl("hdn_Name") as HiddenField;
               if(nameField != null)
               {
                   dropdownlist.SelectedValue = nameField.Value;
               }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thx for correcting. Indeed, I did mismatch DropDownList and TextBox and had to remove the Text field.

Your solution nearly works for me.
I still have an issue with this line :
dropdownlist.SelectedValue = nameField.Value;

It always returns the first item of the list (Pete in this case).
Could there be something wrong with this line?

Comment: Try removing this if statement : `if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)`. I don't think this belongs here for databining?

Comment: Yep I had removed it already and still have the issue mentioned:

`code dropdownlist.SelectedValue = nameField.Value;`

always picking up the first item of the datasource list

Comment: Found the error :)

I copy pasted your code. 
There was a typo :
`code value='Eval("Name")'`
instead of 
 `code value='<%# Eval("Name") %>'`
Once fixed, it works as expected.
Thanks a ton for your assistance on this issue.

Comment: No problem - I've edited the answer to correct that error. Can you mark this as the answer so it helps others as necessary.